# Monitor refresh rate setting not respected after reboot

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I am using Ubuntu with 3 screen setup: laptop and 2 27 inch monitors attached to it. All screens are configured to FullHD and 60Hz. And so far everything is(was) fine.

Recently I changed one of the screens to better model so that it is now able to run 144Hz - I don't need it for work but it is useful when I connect my leisure time device and run Windows.

Anyway, problems started since then. When this screen is configured to run in recommended 144Hz refresh rate I cannot turn second monitor (third screen) on. So I have set refresh rate to 60Hz and everything seemed fine.

Unfortunately, after reboot everything goes back to 144Hz. I have to manually adjust refresh, then turn the monitor on, adjust screen rotations and positions... that's simply annoying.

What's more annoying is that my `~/.config/monitors.xml` setting has clearly proper refresh rate but it seems to be ignored (problematic screen is `ACR` connected to `DP-2-1`):

```
╰> cat .config/monitors.xml 
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="eDP-1">
          <vendor>SHP</vendor>
          <product>0x14d1</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1200</height>
          <rate>59.950000</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>478</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>no</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="DP-1">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-2">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-3">
      </output>
      <output name="DP-2-1">
          <vendor>ACR</vendor>
          <product>0x074e</product>
          <serial>0x02319819</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60.000000</rate>
          <x>1920</x>
          <y>478</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="DP-2-2">
          <vendor>PHL</vendor>
          <product>0x090a</product>
          <serial>0x00009f0a</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60.000000</rate>
          <x>3840</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>left</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>no</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="DP-2-3">
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

EDIT

I also tried to prepare workaround by writing simple script using `xrandr`:

```
#!/bin/bash

#laptop
xrandr --output eDP-1 --pos 0x480

#Acer
xrandr --output DP-2-1 --pos 1920x480 --rate 60 --primary

#Philips
xrandr --output DP-2-2 --pos 3840x0 --rotate left
```

And what I noticed is that `xrandr --output DP-2-1 --rate 60` also gets ignored. I tried `--rate 60.00` because that's exact value listed when I run `xrandr` but it also did not work. The only thing that actually helped was changing refresh rate in GUI and then running script above to setup proper screen positions/rotations.